# Need to find the Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}=3$, where $f$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.

Find $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$.

I tried a lot to solve this question but I didn't succeed. Could you please give me a hint.

Comment: By assumption, $f(x) - 2 = 3(x-1) + o(x-1) [x \to 1]$ . Plug this into the next expression.

Comment: L'Hopital is not applicable. $f'$ is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Check this link to find the conditions to use L'hopitals rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: Could you assume that $\lim_{x\to c} (f'/g') = L$ in your problem? You only know that $f'(1) = 3$ instead of $\lim_{x\to 1} f'(x) = 3$.

Comment: Also L'Hopital requires $f,g$ be differentiable in a neighborhood of $c$, but in your question $f$ is not necessarily differentiable in a neighborhood of $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}=3$ and $f$ is continuous:
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\\
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(x^3f(x)-2x^3)+(2x^3-2x^2)+(2x^2-2x)+(2x-2)+(2-f(1))}{x-1}=\\
\lim_{x\to 1} x^3\cdot \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}+\lim_{x\to 1} 2x^2+\lim_{x\to 1} 2x+2+0=\\
3+2+2+2+0=9.$$

Answer (score 1):

The first statement means $f(1)=2$ and $f'(1)=3$. Then
$$f(1+h)=2+3h+o(h)$$ and so
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^3 f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h)^3(2+3h+o(h))-2}{h}$$
etc.

Comment: If I may ask, what is $o(h)$ ?

Comment: @dmtri https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}=3 \implies f(x)=(x-1)g(x)+2$$

Where $g(x)$ is a continuous function and $$\lim _{x\to1} g(x)=3$$

Thus $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=   \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3(x-1)g(x)+2x^3-f(1)}{x-1}$$

$$=g(1) +\lim_{x\to1}\frac{2x^3-2}{x-1}=3 +6=9$$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your hints, but I think the following is easier for an undergraduate student

The first statement means : $f(1) = 2$ and $f'(1) = 3$, then

$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^3f(x)-f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^3f(x)-2}{x-1}$

If we use the long division, we will get

$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^3f(x)-2}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1}f(x)(x^2+x+1)+\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1}f(x)(x^2+x+1)+\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1} = f(1).3 + 3 = 6+3=9$

Or, we can use L'hopitals rule 
$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^3f(x)-2}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{3x^2f(x) + x^3f'(x)}{1} = 3f(1) + f'(1) = 6+3=9$

Comment: +1 for the simple answer.

Comment: @Ahmed, if I may ask how can you use De L' hospital rule ? The function $f$ is not supposed to be differentiable in a interval containing $1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Second part:

$\dfrac {[(x-1)+1]^3f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=$

${\tiny \dfrac {[(x-1)^3+3(x-1)^2+3(x-1)^1+ 1]f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=}$

${\tiny \dfrac{(x-1)[3(x-1)^2+3(x-1)^1 +3] f(x)+f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=}$

$[3(x-1)^2+3(x-1)^1 +3]f(x) +\dfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1};$

Take the limit $x \rightarrow 1$ making use of the continuity of $f$ , of $f(1)=2$, and of $\lim_{ x \rightarrow 1}\dfrac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f(x)=f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)+o((x-1)^2)$.

From the condition, we have $f(1)=2$ and $f'(1)=3$.

The result is $9$.